# Pentaho unable to copy files to Hadoop HDFS file system 1.0.3

Tags: hadoop, pentaho

This is my first thread and am using using 5.4.0.1-130 Pentaho kettle version.

I have installed hadoop-1.0.3 version in a VM player and I have bridged it using bridged network.

I have Pentaho installed on my desktop on Windows10 and the hadoop is available in the above mentioned VMplayer.

I'm trying to do a "Hadoop Copy File" job, but it fails with the following error.

```
SourceEnvironment: <static>
SourceFile/Folder: file:///C:/Study/Pentaho/data-integrationC:/Study/Pentaho/data-integration
DestinationEnvironment: <static>
Destination File/Folder: hdfs://notroot/hadoop123@192.168.139.128:8020/input
```

I tried to copy and create a folder C:\Study\Pentaho\data-integration\plugins\pentaho-big-data-plugin\hadoop-configurations\hadoop-103\lib as per the instruction mentioned in this website(http://funpdi.blogspot.in/2013/03/pe...nd-hadoop.html), still no luck.

Kindly advice what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
015/09/07 11:56:02 - Hadoop Copy Files - Processing row source File/folder source : [file:///C:/Study/Pentaho/data-integrationC:/Study/Pentaho/data-integration] ... destination file/folder : [hdfs://notroot/hadoop123@192.168.139.128:8020/input]... wildcard : [^.*\.txt]
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : Can not copy file/folder [file:///C:/Study/Pentaho/data-integrationC:/Study/Pentaho/data-integration] to [hdfs://notroot/hadoop123@192.168.139.128:8020/input]. Exception : [
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - 
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - Unable to get VFS File object for filename 'hdfs://notroot/hadoop123@192.168.139.128:8020/input' : Could not resolve file "hdfs://notroot/hadoop123@192.168.139.128:8020/input".
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - 
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - ]
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleFileException: 
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - 
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - Unable to get VFS File object for filename 'hdfs://notroot/hadoop123@192.168.139.128:8020/input' : Could not resolve file "hdfs://notroot/hadoop123@192.168.139.128:8020/input".
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - 
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - 
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getFileObject(KettleVFS.java:154)
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getFileObject(KettleVFS.java:102)
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.copyfiles.JobEntryCopyFiles.ProcessFileFolder(JobEntryCopyFiles.java:421)
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.copyfiles.JobEntryCopyFiles.execute(JobEntryCopyFiles.java:375)
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:716)
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:859)
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:532)
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Hadoop Copy Files - at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:424)
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - pentaho_to_hadoop_ex3ktr - Finished job entry [Hadoop Copy Files] (result=[false])
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - pentaho_to_hadoop_ex3ktr - Job execution finished
2015/09/07 11:56:04 - Spoon - Job has ended.
```

Comment: I guess we wont be able to connect latest Pentaho version 5.4 with old Hadoop version 1.0.4......

Hence I decided to install cloudera and now able to do the connection, but still unable to place the files from desktop to HDFS.

I will keep you guys posted on the outcome. BTW, am using coudera also a older version 3x...